# Git refetch based on new origin and prune old cache

Tags: git, github

I work in a company where we have a monorepo, and other devs would create private branch in the form of '/'. So a 'git dag' is pretty messy.

I've then set my [remote "origin"] in the git config to only track main branch and my personal branch, so that I'm not pulling any newly private branch by others, but there are still other existing private branch of others (I think they're cache?) when I do 'git branch -a' (and in 'git dag'). How do I do a reset & refetch only preserve the ones that I care?

Answer (score 0):

Try first a [`git fetch --prune origin`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt--p) to see if it respect your refspec, and [prune](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_pruning) your remote tracking branches that you do not fetch.
Same idea with [`git remote prune origin`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-empruneem)

If not, you would need a loop listing your remote tracking branch and check if you have a local one with the same name (if not, delete your remote tracking branch)

Something like:

```bash
# Loop over all remote tracking branches
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/remotes | while read branch; do
  # Get the local name of the branch without origin/
  local_name=${branch#origin/}
  git show-ref --verify --quiet refs/heads/$local_name
  if [ $? -neq 0 ]; then
     git branch --delete --remotes origin/$local_name
  fi
done
```